# where can I get the selenium-python 'Page' module to install?

Tags: python, selenium, module

On the Selenium web site there is a section about the 'Page' object:
`https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html`

The first code example on that page is labeled '6.1. Test case' and has a line `import page`.

I run this sample code and get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'page'`

I do not get any errors on the other import statements. Trying pip install page fails. I look through pypi.org and plenty of page* modules return but I can not recognise the one I need. I see plenty of reference to post through out the web from users relating to the 'Page' object and all are without mention of where to locate the 'Page' module. I read through the selenium module and do not see a 'Page' class.

How do I locate this Page module for install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Page' isn't a module that you can install through pip, nor is it installed when you download selenium. It's an example in their documentation. If you scroll down a bit you see the entire code of that document. If you wish to use it, simply copy the code into a 'page.py' file in the same directory as your original file and you're set.

You can find the code [right here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-object-classes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do this a lot, focusing on the question as I encounter it rather than reading on. However, I hate reading a doc further to find no answer to questions left open by the author. This makes me basically abandon the doc. Bacically go to stackoverflow ask lame question

Even still, I would have missed what you have given me and that is a lot more than the question I asked.  I was looking for how to assemble the language also and now I have that answer too. Again, Thank you very much.

Now can you tell me how do I mark this post as answered and give you the credit?

Comment: @nobody you’re welcome! I really do recommend reading the docs. It usually contains a lot of important and interesting information that can save you a lot of time and effort. People will generally also be a lot more compelled to help. You can just upvote the answer if it helped and it has a greyed out checkmark right underneath

Comment: Yea, I had to turn off the dark reader to see it.

Comment: @nobody Added a sentence like this: `The following section will introduce the page module where the page objects will be defined.` Let me know if that's going to be a bit helpful for a new reader.

Comment: @baijum Yes, the line helps. Any notes on the page giving reference to read on is much appreciated. It is hard to read an entire doc and then review the document in its entire form in order to gain an understanding of it. I think it is better to be able to read and ascertain information as we go along rather than try to mentally compile a sort of index used to cross reference and recheck.

I am not trained to know that key words like 'design pattern' should clue me into a manner in which the doc should be approached.

It is admirable that you have taken time to address this situation!

Comment: @nobody Thanks for the kind words. If you notice any issue with the documentation. Feel free to raise an issue or send PRs :)